# How to I insert a website into a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an API response that returns html, I want to insert the response into my react component

I've already tried

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: myApi.response }} />
```

However this throws off my entire layout as it has its own css and scripts.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? If you need it to be independent of your site use a frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an iframe and set its html, then change the iframe style

```
  const iframeRef = React.useRef(null)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (iframeRef && iframeRef.current) {
      const apiResponse = `
        <html>
        <body style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background: lime">
          Hello
        </body>
        </html>
      `;
      const doc = iframeRef.current.contentWindow.document;
      doc.open();
      doc.write(apiResponse);
      doc.close();
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <iframe ref={iframeRef} />
    </div>
  );
```

Take a look https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-wood-jpf79?file=/src/App.js